# How to reconfigure html and flask code to load the bootstrap table once and then reload the data table after each new item of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, tensorflow, bootstrap-4

I am using flask and bootstrap to code a website involving tensor-flow.
Currently, the user enters code into a form, then flask and html code loads the page after all the data has been computed; causing an enormous buffering time for the form page. So, I want the table to load once--empty--then reload once the user clicks on the table(or after a set time or new piece of data) with the new computed data inside the table.

Here is all the relevant flask code:(the following code takes the numbers from the multiperceptron page and uses those numbers to run a tensor flow neural network, then it adds the number of images seen so far and training accuracy numbers to a dictionary)

```
@app.route('/MultiPerceptron')
def MultiPerceptron():
    return render_template("MultiPerceptron.html")
@app.route('/MultiPerceptronForm', methods=["POST"])
def MultiPerceptronForm():
    #setting up of the tensor flow computational graph...
    #the tensor flow session which creates the data that I will add to the data table
    MultiPerceptResult=dict()
    # Launch the graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        # Training cycle
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            avg_cost = 0.
            total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
            images_seen_per_epoch = total_batch * batch_size
            # Loop over all batches
            for i in range(total_batch):
                batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
                # Compute average loss
                avg_cost += c / total_batch
            # Display logs per epoch step
            if epoch % display_step == 0:
                images_seen = epoch * images_seen_per_epoch
                print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                    "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
                # Test model
                correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
                # Calculate accuracy
                accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
                print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
                #adding the new data to the dictionary****
                MultiPerceptResult[images_seen] = accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})

    return render_template('MultiPerceptronForm.html', MultiPerceptResult=MultiPerceptResult)
```

Here is all the relevant html code:(the following html code is taking the dictionary made by the flask code and iterating through it to create a table that holds all that data)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Images Seen</th>
                <th>Training Accuracy</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for key, value in MultiPerceptResult.items() %}
            <tr>
                <th> {{ key }} </th>
                <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You may have to use AJAX calls to update the page. Then everytime the user clicks the page is updated without reloading.

Now if you want the server to update the page for itself, without the user doing nothing, its more tricky. Either you could make a loop for AJAX polling the server every X seconds, or better use Websockets (in your case Flask-SocketIO)

Comment: Could you show me a piece of example code to implement inside my flask code? I'm not familiar with websocketsc or AJAX. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest part is Flask itself... Basically you'll use Javascript/JQuery to poll the server and update the page...
Maybe can help:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/
or
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-ajax
or
https://pythonprogramming.net/jquery-flask-tutorial/

Comment: I'm interested in doing the on click of button updating, but I have been looking across the web for example code and couldn't find anything. Could you please show an example of javascript/jquery code populating a html table? Also, I would be okay with the table updating whenever new data is calculated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax/JQuery example

From the [Oficial docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/):

**app.py**

```
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='.')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/ajax')
def ajax():
    a = request.args.get('a', 1, type=int)
    b = request.args.get('b', 100, type=int)
    rand = random.randint(a, b)
    return jsonify(result=rand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="a"]').val(1);
        $('input[name="b"]').val(1000);
        $('a#calculate').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/ajax', {
                a: $('input[name="a"]').val(),
                b: $('input[name="b"]').val()
            }, function(data) {
                $(".my_table").append("<tr><td>Number</td><td>" + data.result + "</td></tr>");
        });
        return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    </script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>AJAX Example</h1>
    <table class="my_table">
    <tr>
    <th>Random</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>Random Numbers from</h2>
    <p><input type=text size=5 name=a> to
    <input type=text size=5 name=b>
    <p><a href=# id=calculate>UPDATE server side</a>
</body>
```